# rails migration to move foreign key to third join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, database-schema

My fleet management rails app has two models

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fleets
end

class Fleet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end
```

fleets table has location_id as foreign key and a `state` column which represent state (active, inactive, new) of fleet. Now i want to write migration to move this relation into third model called `Allotment`. My models should look like this

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :allotments
  has_many :fleets, :through => :allotments
end
class Fleet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :allotments
  has_many :branches, :through => :allotments
end
class Allotment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fleet
  belongs_to :location
end
```

What is the best way to write migration to -

1. remove foreign key `location_id` from `fleets` and populate records in `allotments` table at the same time.
2. move `state` column from `fleets` to `allotments` and populate it as well
3. How to make these migration reversible without breaking code.

Is it good to write migration as below ? or should i write two separate migration, one to create `allotments` and populate it, other to remove column from `fleets` ? Am i missing anything critical in below migration ?

```
def self.up 
  create_table :allotments do |t|
    t.references :fleet, index: true
    t.references :location, index: true
    t.string :state
  end
  Fleet.all.each do |f|
    l = f.location
    Allotment.create(fleet: f, location: l, state: f.state)
  end
  remove_reference :fleets, :location, index: true
  remove_column :fleets, :state
end 
self.down
  add_refrence :fleets, :location, index: true
  add_column :fleets, :state, :string
  Fleet.all.each do |f|
    f.update_column :state, f.allotments.first.state
    f.update_column :location_id, f.locations.first.id
  end
  drop_table :allotments
end
```

Comment: I found one problem in my migration. It won't be reversible if `f.allotments.first` returns nil in `self.down`. How do i proceed here ?

Comment: After a lot of reading here and there, i decided not to use Model in migration to update/create data.

Comment: Two things: don't use `def self.up`, but rather, [`reversible`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-reversible), and you can use models within the migration, provided that you redefine the classes yourself, inside the migration class.